# How to pass bash parameter to awk script?

Tags: file, bash, awk

I have awk file:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {

}
{
        filetime[$'$colnumber']++;
}
END {
        for (i in filetime) {
                print filetime[i],i;
        }
}
```

And bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
awk -f myawk.awk
```

When I run:

```
ls -la | ./countPar.sh 5
```

I receive error:

```
ls -la | ./countPar.sh 5
awk: myawk.awk:6:         filetime[$'$colnumber']++;
awk: myawk.awk:6:                   ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

Why? $colnumber must be replaced with 5, so awk should read 5th column of ls ouput.
Thanks.

Comment: this seems like a followup of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8551780/226201 as others have pointed out, bash environment and awk environment are separate, if you want to pass arguments from one to the other it has to be made explicit.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass variables to your awk script directly from the command line.

Change this line:

```
filetime[$'$colnumber']++;
```

To:

```
filetime[colnumber]++;
```

And run:

```
ls -al | awk -f ./myawk.awk -v colnumber=5
```

If you really want to use a bash wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
awk -f myawk.awk colnumber=$var1
```

(with the same change in your script as above.)

If you want to use environment variables use:

```
#!/bin/bash
export var1=$1
awk -f myawk.awk
```

and:

```
filetime[ENVIRON["var1"]]++;
```

(I really don't understand what the purpose of your awk script is though. The last part could be simplified to:

```
END { print filetime[colnumber],colnumber; }
```

and parsing the output of `ls` is generally a bad idea.)

Comment: The sense is combine bash and awk. The input parameter I get only for example, bash script is more complicate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, so added more options. You can't have plain shell substitution inside your awk script, that just will not work - the shell only does substitutions on its parameters, not inside random files you specify on the command line (it doesn't even check what is a file and what is not in the general case).

Comment: Interesting; I wasn't aware that you could pass in variables to awk without using -v

Comment: @twqqis: see e.g. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34255/are-there-2-ways-to-set-awk-vars-via-command-line), the behavior with/without `-v` is slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
awk -v colnumber="${var}" -f /your/script
```

But within your `awk` script, you don't need the `$` in front of colnumber.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Passing 3 variable to script myscript.sh
var1 is the column number on which condition has set.
While var2 & var3 are input and temp file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3
awk -v col="${var1}" -f awkscript.awk ${var2} > $var3
mv ${var3} ${var2}
```

execute it like below -

```
./myscript.sh 2 file.txt temp.txt
```